# Is there a dataset available similar to AFINN (Each word is score between -5 and +5 based on the sentiment) in French?

Tags: python, r, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a sentimental analysis of a french dataset in both R and Python. I know there is a dataset for english like AFINN where each word is rated for sentiment. I am looking for something similar for French where I could see a dataset which gives you numerical score for each of the words

Below is a simple query in R to get the sore of AFINN

```
get_sentiments("afinn")
```

Please let me know if there is any datasource available for French words.

Thanks

```
get_sentiments("afinn")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is off-topic. But since I ran into the same kind of issues, here are two datasets:

Lexicoder Sentiment Dictionary from université Laval in Canada: 
https://www.poltext.org/en/donnees-et-analyses/lexicoder

French Expanded Emotion Lexicon: http://advanse.lirmm.fr/feel.php

In both cases read how the lexicons have been created and if you are allowed to use them.